# How to build a hash table with python?

Tags: python, hashtable

I want to build a hash table by linear probing with python I have a list of employeesID and employeesName, I want to put that data in hash table

this is my code :

```
employeeID = [107,35,25,13,101,43,98,57,1,2,3,4]

employeeName = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","Err"]

class HashTable:
  hashSize = 11
  totalMember = 0

  def_init_(self):
    self.hashTable = [[None] * 2 for i in range(self.hashSize)]
```

this is the output I want

```
Adding 4 : Hash is Overflow
0  98  g
1  1   i
2  35  b
3  25  c
4  13  d
5  101 e
6  57  h
7  2   j
8  107 a
9  3   k
10 43  f
```

So what next I have a dead end right here

***Sorry for my bad English***

Comment: https://stephenagrice.medium.com/how-to-implement-a-hash-table-in-python-1eb6c55019fd

Comment: `hashtable = dict(zip(employeeID, employeeName))`?

Comment: This is already done internally with a Python `dict`. Do you really want to re-implement this on your own?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Comment: the out put is not the same

Answer (score 0):

If `employeeID` and `employeeName` are the same lengths, you can do

```
employeeID = [107,35,25,13,101,43,98,57,1,2,3,4]
employeeName = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"]

hash = dict(zip(employeeName,employeeID)

#result

{'a': 107, 'b': 35, 'c': 25, 'd': 13, 'e': 101, 'f': 43, 'g': 98, 'h': 57, 'i': 1, 'j': 2, 'k': 3, 'L': 4}
```